# How to unfold a dictionary of dictionaries into a pandas DataFrame for larger dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Consider the following dictionary of dictionaries in python3.x

```
dict1 = {4: {4:25, 5:39, 3:42}, 5:{24:94, 252:49, 25:4, 55:923}}
```

I would like to unfold this into a pandas DataFrame. There appear to be two options:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1, orient='columns')

print(df1)
        4      5
3    42.0    NaN
4    25.0    NaN
5    39.0    NaN
24    NaN   94.0
25    NaN    4.0
55    NaN  923.0
252   NaN   49.0
```

whereby the columns for this are the main dictionary keys `4` and `5', the row indices are the subdictionary keys and the values are the subdictionary values.

The other option is

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1, orient='index')
print(df2)
    4     5     3     24    252  25     55 
4  25.0  39.0  42.0   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
5   NaN   NaN   NaN  94.0  49.0  4.0  923.0
```

whereby the columns are the keys of the inner "sub-dictionary", the row indices are the keys of the main dictionary, and the values are the subdictionary keys.

Is there a standard approach which allows us to unfold the python dictionary as follows?

```
key inner_key values
4        3      42 
4        4      25
4        5      39
5        24     94
5        25     4
5        55     923
5        252    49
```

It would be best not to manipulate the DataFrame after using `from_dict()`, as for far larger python dictionaries, this could become quite memory intensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### List comprehension

A list comprehension should be fairly efficient:

```
dict1 = {4: {4:25, 5:39, 3:42}, 5: {24:94, 252:49, 25:4, 55:923}}

cols = ['key', 'inner_key', 'values']

df = pd.DataFrame([[k1, k2, v2] for k1, v1 in dict1.items() for k2, v2 in v1.items()],
                  columns=cols).sort_values(cols)

print(df)

   key  inner_key  values
2    4          3      42
0    4          4      25
1    4          5      39
3    5         24      94
5    5         25       4
6    5         55     923
4    5        252      49
```

#### [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html) + [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

If you don't mind working from `df1`, you can unpivot your dataframe via `pd.melt` and then drop rows with null `value`.

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()

res = pd.melt(df1, id_vars='index', value_vars=[4, 5])\
        .dropna(subset=['value']).astype(int)

print(res)

    index  variable  value
0       3         4     42
1       4         4     25
2       5         4     39
10     24         5     94
11     25         5      4
12     55         5    923
13    252         5     49
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.DataFrame([[i,j,user_dict[i][j] ] for i in user_dict.keys() for j in user_dict[i].keys()],columns=['key', 'inner_key', 'values'])
```

Output:

```
   key  inner_key   values
0   4   4           25
1   4   5           39
2   4   3           42
3   5   24          94
4   5   252         49
5   5   25          4
6   5   55         923
```